# Image appear as blank document print

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out why is my coupon image appear as a blank when trying to print it, is it because of popup function of the javascript onclick? Well I have tried to target it as well in javascript, but I have no luck. One more thing the platform I'm using has an inline onclick function you can see here : Get Coupon 
http://thecameldevelopers.editor.multiscreensite.com/preview/fcaad832

```
$(function(){

 console.log(' jquery is working');
 function print(){
     //find the div container with the image of coupon
     var src =  $('.popupData').find('img').attr('src');
      //test the src if ok 
    console.log(src);
    popup.document.write('<img src=\"'+ src + '\"'+ '/>');
    var popup = window.open();
    popup.focus();
    popup.print();

}
  });
```